# Stack: cover bottom child with top child

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want overlay a widget over the bottom widget to hide it. hence I use stack. I don't know the bottom widget size so I can't give top widget fixed size.

what I have:

[image]

what I want to achieve:

[image]

```
Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Text(
        'Winner: ',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 34),
      ),
      Stack(
        children: [
          Text('YOU!!!', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 34)),
          Container(
            color: Colors.amber,
          )
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

This is simplified version of what I want to achive. I have to use Row and assume Texts are any widget with any size.

Stack sizes its children based on the Constraint it receives from parent not based on children sizes.

how can I overlay top widget with exact size of bottom widget?

Comment: Does [this](https://blog.gskinner.com/archives/2020/09/flutter-tricks-widget-size-position.html) help?

Comment: I think I have to write custom RenderObject to calculate top child size based on bottom child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Positioned.Fill` solved the problem:

`Positioned.Fill` Creates a Positioned object with [left], [top], [right], and [bottom] set to 0.0 unless a value for them is passed.
so the Positioned child get stretched to the edges of the stack's biggest child.

```
Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Text(
        'Winner: ',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 34),
      ),
      Stack(
        children: [
          Text('YOU!!!', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 34)),
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: Indeed, this is more efficient!

Answer (score 0):

To know the size of your `widget` and apply things depending on this, you can use GlobalKey like this `GlobalKey key;`. Initialize it in your `initSate` and listen to it's size

```
GlobalKey key;
double yourWidgetWidth;
double yourWidgetHeight;

@override
initState() {
   // .... other stuffs
   
   key = GlobalKey();

   WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (mounted) {
         yourWidgetWidth = containerKey.currentContext.size.width;
         yourWidgetHeight = containerKey.currentContext.size.height;
      }
   });
}
```

And with `yourWidgetWidth` and `yourWidgetHeight` you can achieve what you want

**Edit**
Here is a concept of what am trying to explain

```
// In variable declaration scope
GlobalKey youTextKey = GlobalKey();
ValueNotifier widthNotifier = ValueNotifier(0);
ValueNotifier heightNotifier = ValueNotifier(0);

// In initState
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  if (mounted) {
    widthNotifier.value = youTextKey.currentContext.size.width - 1.0;
    heightNotifier.value = youTextKey.currentContext.size.height - 5.0;
  }
});

// Your row
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Text(
      'Winner: ',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 34),
    ),
    Stack(
      children: [
        Text('YOU!!!', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 34), key: youTextKey,),
        ValueListenableBuilder(
          valueListenable: widthNotifier,
          builder: (context, width, _) {
            return ValueListenableBuilder(
              valueListenable: heightNotifier,
              builder: (context, height, _) {
                return Container(
                  width: width,
                  height: height,
                  color: Colors.amber,
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: I have to layout widgets to know their sizes. so its not helpful. Also I'm looking for declarative way instead of imperative.

Comment: I've faced this kind of things in the past. Maybe you can check my new edit

Comment: Thanks for contributing, see the answer